# UITextField blue background, out of the blue

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a couple of UITextField elements in a UITableView. I can edit them freely, but for reasons I can't understand or easily reproduce - sometimes, one of the fields will get a blue background and will stay that way. Editing still works, it's just painted blue for some reason.

[image]

What am I missing?

Trying my app on an iPad 3. Xcode 4.3.x, IOS 5.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the cell that get's selected as well... I think this should do the trick:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```